# "Legally" filling a 10x10 table with 10 of each digit

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Professor Halfbrain has spent his entire weekend by filling $10\times10$ tables with the digits $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ so that each digit occurs exactly $10$ times. According to the professor, such fillings are called *legal* fillings.
Halfbrain detected oodles and oodles of fascinating legal fillings, and he derived two extremely deep theorems on them:

> **Professor Halfbrain's first theorem**: In every legal filling of a $10\times10$ table, there exists a row or a column that contains at least *two* different digits.
>
> **Professor Halfbrain's second theorem**: There exists a legal filling of a $10\times10$ table, in which every row and every column contain at most *ten* different digits.

This puzzle asks you to improve the two theorems of professor Halfbrain and to make them even deeper.
Find an integer $x$, so that "at least two different digits" in the first theorem may be replaced by "at least $x$ different digits", and so that "at most ten different digits" in the second theorem may be replaced by "at most $x$ different digits" (again yielding true statements, of course).

Comment: In the second theorem, surely "at most ten" means *exactly* ten since there are only ten digits to play with?

Comment: It must be two different integers $x$ that replace 2 in the first theorem and 10 in the second, right? Maybe you could rephrase the last paragraph a little to make this clear.

Comment: 1. In the second theorem, the term  "at most ten" yields a correct statement. (I have seen professor Halfbrain's proof, and it was clear and correct.) --- 2. The last paragraph refers to a single integer x, and it of course is the same x in both statements.

Comment: Ah, so the maximum $x$ such that the first theorem holds is also the minimum $x$ such that the second holds. I get it now. Nice puzzle! Maybe the [sudoku] tag?

Comment: 1. Yes, that's correct.  --- 2. No, it got nothing to do with sudoku.

Comment: Is there a legal filling which has less than ten rows or columns with at least four different digits?

Comment: Do digits which are the same need to be adjacent to each other? What constitutes a "legal" filling?

Comment: @curiousdannii --- a filling is legal, if each of the 10 digits occurs exactly 10 times.

Comment: It took me a while to fully comprehend the absurdity of Professor Halfbrain's theorems...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can fill the grid so that every row and column has at most

> $4$

different digits as follows:

> [image]

This is optimal. Here's why we can't do better.

> Say each row and column had at most $3$ distinct digits. Label each row and column with those digits. There are at most $60$ digit labels, so some digit appears in most $6$ labels, say $r$ row labels and $c$ column labels. Since only those rows and columns may contain that digit, it appears at most $rc$ times in the grid. But since $r+c\leq 6$, we must have $rc\leq 9$ (maximized for $r=c=3$), so that digit can't appear $10$ times in the grid. Contradiction.

Comment: I don't question your answer but could you explain how you came to 60 labels and why that automatically means at most 6 labels? I don't understand it. Also, how did you find the filling? Was some strategy involved or just trial and error?

Comment: @IvoBeckers 10 rows + 10 columns = 20 Labels. And each Label consists of at most 3 digits! So If I write all of my labels down they consists of at most 3x20 = 60 digits. We have 10 digits - if each digit would appear 7 times we would need 70 digit-spaces in these labels. So not every digit can appear 7 or more times in the labels. So there has to be 1 digit, which only appears 6 or fewer times... This digit will hence only be present in 5 rows and 1 column, or 4 rows and 2 columns or 3 rows and 3 columns. None of which are enough spaces to appear 10 times!

Comment: @Falco Thanks for the explanation. I know understand

Comment: This (your original answer) proves theorem 2 for x = 4. Interestingly, your proof of why x > 3 for theorem 2 also shows that x > 3 in theorem 1. So x = 4 satisfies both theorems.

Comment: @IvoBeckers I liked 2x5 blocks for being compact and not having anything stick out, so I tried placing them lots of different ways. The spiral-ish pattern was nice for having lines cross blocks both the short way and the long way.

Comment: I assume I am not the only person who thought the pattern of no more than 4 different digits in each row and column as... the Final Solution.

Answer (score 6):

for an $M$ by $M$ table where $M$ is of the form $n*n$ then it would be $x = n$ I think. So for $M=9$ then $x=3$ and this is a solution:

```
111222333
111222333
111222333
444555666
444555666
444555666
777888999
777888999
777888999
```

since 10 has no integer square root my guess it would be the square root rounded up. So my guess is $x=4$. I have no solution (yet) though

Comment: great intuitive approach!